# Present a Different View Controller After Dismissing a Modal View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I present a modal view controller for various UI settings in an iOS app.  One of those settings allows the user to select a different main view.  When they hit "Done" I want to dismiss the modal view and have the newly-selected view controller appear, without a momentary delay where the old view controller segues to the new view controller.  How could this be implemented?

**Update:**

Here is a method I successfully implemented using Eugene's technique, but without the app delegate.  Instead, this implementation is specific to my scenario where a view controller in a navigation stack presents the modal view controller in a Utility app.

```
- (void)swapFrontSideViewController;
{
    UINavigationController *navigationVC = (UINavigationController *)[self presentingViewController];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers      = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:navigationVC.viewControllers];
    UIViewControllerSubclass *selectedViewController = nil;
    if ([self.selectedFrontSide isEqualToString:FRONT_SIDE_NAME1]) {
        selectedViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:FRONT_SIDE_NAME1];
    } else if ([self.selectedFrontSide isEqualToString:FRONT_SIDE_NAME2]) {
        selectedViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:FRONT_SIDE_NAME2];
    }
    if (selectedViewController) {
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:viewControllers.count -1 withObject:selectedViewController];
        [navigationVC setViewControllers:viewControllers];
        self.delegate = selectedViewController;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Undefined Front Side Selected.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)doDismiss:(id)sender {
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; // Get the app delegate
  NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.navigationController.viewControllers]; // fetch its navigationController viewControllers stack
  UIViewController *replacementController; //initialize replacement controller
  [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:viewControllers.count -1 withObject:replacementController]; // replace the top view controller in stack with the replacement one
  [appDelegate.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers]; //change the stack
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: +1 for the way you fetch the `UIViewControllers` and replace it. -1 for the kind of architecture you put in place.

Comment: I have to be honest with you, I don't really like to have any kind of reference or connection with the `AppDelegate`, it creates an attachment that I bet that if you think a bit more you will find a solution that doesn't need that reference. Makes the code simpler and avoid tight coupling.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there.  Clever.  I'll give this a go later today, thanks.

Comment: @JackyBoy Of course one can simply use presentingViewController property and fetch its navigation controller, but this solution is only viable for iOS 5+. Can't really see any logic in not liking any sorts of connections with AppDelegate, since even Apple's default CoreData templates are (or were) created around AppDelegate instead of a separate singleton data access layer class. Anyways, I see no harm in this code, but thanks for your point.

Comment: Well if the only solution is really using the `AppDelegate` then so be it.. I just don't like to have logic and interaction between `UIViewControllers` to be managed by `AppDelegate`, it really doesn't make sense to me, specially when you can do it somewhere else.